# WordPress 'Contact Form 7' form generating inconsistent fields

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms

I've used the [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) plugin *Contact Form 7* to create a very simple questionnaire.
Upon reviewing the final output, I've noticed that two fields *(Your Birthday, Your Email)* are *(seemingly randomly)* generated incorrectly - they seem to be stacked on top of one another.

The form can be viewed [here](http://golddiggerinc.com/design-questionnaire/).

I've not really done any custom styling here, and I didn't see any obvious inconsistencies in [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29), so I can't imagine what is causing the trouble?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Firebug I modify this [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets),

```
.your-name, .your-email {
    float: left;
    width: 365px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

by

```
.your-name, .your-email {
    width: 365px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

That's to mean I remove **float:left**, and the form looks great. So you have the clear the float.

Here is the final result: [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3q2DOPnNwNhWWFJOHJfVlNBcHM/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

Check your [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) structure. The way you're currently doing them isn't that great. Try:

```
<p> Name </p>
<p> Form input here </p>
```

instead of using lots of 
 tags, and make sure you are `clear: both;` ing the `p` tags so all `p` tags take up one line.